# Group XML child nodes if a matching child element is there

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation, xslt-grouping

I have an XML containing information about multiple records.

I want the child elements to be grouped based on a matching child node.

I need an XSLT scripts that does the following

> I want to group all the *'info'* tags into one *'body'* if *'MainId'*
>   is same for multiple *'body'* elements. I need this grouping to be
>   done irrespective of values in the other nodes inside the *'body'*.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns="12345">
<Main>
    <Header>
        <DateTime>2019-02-21- 6:36:43 PM</DateTime>
        <NbOfRecords>2</NbOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Id>1000198</Id>
        <Info>
            <CustId>
                <Id>
                    <MainId>AB123</MainId>
                </Id>
            </CustId>
            <AddInfo>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="Test">149500</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="Test">0</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
            </AddInfo>
        </Info>
    </Body>
    <Body>
        <Id>1000199</Id>
        <Info>
            <CustId>
                <Id>
                    <MainId>AB123</MainId>
                </Id>
            </CustId>
            <AddInfo>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="Test">16000</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="Test">0</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
            </AddInfo>
        </Info>
    </Body>
    <Body>
        <Id>1000200</Id>
        <Info>
            <CustId>
                <Id>
                    <MainId>BC124</MainId>
                </Id>
            </CustId>
            <AddInfo>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="GBP">16000</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="GBP">12000</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
            </AddInfo>
        </Info>
    </Body>
</Main>
```

**Expected output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns="12345">
<Main>
    <Header>
        <DateTime>2019-02-21- 6:36:43 PM</DateTime>
        <NbOfRecords>2</NbOfRecords>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Id>1000198</Id>
        <Info>
            <CustId>
                <Id>
                    <MainId>AB123</MainId>
                </Id>
            </CustId>
            <AddInfo>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="Test">149500</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="Test">0</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="Test">16000</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="Test">0</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
            </AddInfo>
        </Info>
    </Body>
    <Body>
        <Id>1000200</Id>
        <Info>
            <CustId>
                <Id>
                    <MainId>BC124</MainId>
                </Id>
            </CustId>
            <AddInfo>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <ActAmt Ccy="GBP">16000</ActAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <Amt>
                        <NegAmt Ccy="GBP">12000</NegAmt>
                    </Amt>
                </info>
            </AddInfo>
        </Info>
    </Body>
</Main>
```

Here is the XSLT containing my input XML: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifp9

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Come back if you have a *specific* question.

Comment: Tried using muenchian grouping, but I am sure it's not right, it doesn't seem to work http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m9

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can you guide me to correct this script http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7m9

Comment: Sorry, no. If that's what you took from the article, there's nothing I can do to help you.